# Why am I seeing DEBUG level logs in my output?

Tags: python, command-line, terminal

I am using logger.debug and a statement inside and I am seeing that DEBUG statement in my output /command line terminal. I thought logger.debug is not supposed to show up unless in verbose mode.. why is this?

Comment: Bash has no "logger.debug". What logging facility are you actually using?

Comment: its in my python script that I'm running for my CLI. Im using logging module btw

Comment: Because you enabled it somewhere. Show a minimal example that I can run to reproduce the issue

Comment: Please provide a minimal yet complete example that reproduces the bug so that we can see your code in action. Have you established a logging file?